# D3: How to set symbols insted of points in a ScatterPlot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm newbie with D3 and I'm trying to put symbols instead points in a scatter plot but something I'm doing bad.

My D3 version is 5.16

This is the code:

```
  setPointsToCanvas(canvas, data, scales, x_label, y_label, lang) {
    canvas
      .selectAll("marks")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("x", d => scales.xScale(d.value_x))
      .attr("y", d => scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y)))
      .attr(
        "d",
        d3
          .symbol()
          .type(d3.symbolCross)
          .size("200")
      );
  }
```

But the result that I've got is nothing :(

[image]

You can find all the code here:

[image: Edit multiple-scatter-plot]

The file where is the code is "MultipleScatterPlot.js"

Comment: *"But the result that I've got is nothing"*... not exactly, look at the top left corner: the symbols are all there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG paths have no `x` or `y` attributes. For positioning them, you have to use `translate`. In your case:

```
.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + scales.xScale(d.value_x) + "," 
    + scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y)) + ")")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciated help @Gerardo Furtado!!! It works!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `path` element do **NOT** support `x` or `y` attribute, you need to switch to `transform`:

```js
// Line219
.attr("transform", d => "translate(" + [
        scales.xScale(d.value_x),
        scales.yScale(parseFloat(d.value_y))
      ] + ")")
.attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross).size("200"))
.attr("fill", "red");
```